# How to change list column text color according to field values in SIEBEL HI?

Tags: list, applet, siebel, text-coloring

Is there a way to change the color of the text according to field value ?
It will be good if there is a way of doing this without scripting, if it is impossible then how to do it with scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HI Form applet controls can be controlled to change font, color, size etc, using javascripting and the FindActivexControl method. But for list applets, these will not work. If you are really confident, you could try modifying the .swt files for the applet, that's where the fonts are decided. But this is not recommended by Siebel.